# How do I alternate the background color of children within a LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

With a short list, rather than going through a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView`, I have opted to use a LinearLayout where I manually populate the children.

How can I alternative the background color of these children to get a striped look within my LinearLayout?

Comment: You should be able to just set the background property alternately on the child views: `android:background="@color/white"`, `android:background="@color/gray"`

Answer (score 1):

Your layout children are usually descendents of the View class so you can use the

```
View.setBackroundResources(int);
```